# Why doesn’t my WiFi card work or show up on my dual booted MacBook Pro 2020?

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot, broadcom, macbook

I have tried to uninstall drivers and reinstall them, I’ve tried to install drivers specifically for the Broadcom WiFi card and it did not work. The WiFi card will show up but it is inactive. I’ve been able to use Ethernet with it so far but it has its limitations. Please let me know if I’m doing anything wrong and how to correct this issue.

Comment: I do apologize, I’m relatively new to Linux and I was following an old tutorial and this part of it did not work. What all information do you need from my Mack book and version to help?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with a Macbook Pro 2013 running Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop. While the OG poster does see their wireless device, mine is not detected at all.

- Intel Cote i7
- Intel HD Graphics 4000 NVE7
- Firmware version: 429.0.0.0.0
- GNOME Version: 44.3
- Window system: Wayland
- Kernel version: Linux 6.2.0-26-generic

Comment: I cannot edit my comment above so: UPDATE: The instructions here worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers :: I now have a flashing UI :( but that is a new problem and it is probably unrelated.